# Filter out the readable file descriptors with poll function

Tags: python, select

I have a code error with:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 285, in ssl_wrap_socket
rd, _, _ = select.select([sock], [], [], sock.gettimeout())
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

It means too many file descriptors with `select()` function.  The code is [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py).
Maybe for reasons of portability, the code uses `select()` to filter out the readable descriptors,
but I need unlimited file descriptor numbers, so I have to change the code with poll function.
The code runs on Linux systems; portable thinking will be ignored.
Here is my code for get rd.  I am new to `poll()` function; is there any problem in my implementation?

The function will look like this:

```
def ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None, cert_reqs=None,
                    ca_certs=None, server_hostname=None,
                    ssl_version=None, ca_cert_dir=None):
    ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(_openssl_versions[ssl_version])
    if certfile:
        keyfile = keyfile or certfile  # Match behaviour of the normal python ssl library
        ctx.use_certificate_file(certfile)
    if keyfile:
        ctx.use_privatekey_file(keyfile)
    if cert_reqs != ssl.CERT_NONE:
        ctx.set_verify(_openssl_verify[cert_reqs], _verify_callback)
    if ca_certs or ca_cert_dir:
        try:
            ctx.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
        except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
            raise ssl.SSLError('bad ca_certs: %r' % ca_certs, e)
    else:
        ctx.set_default_verify_paths()

    # Disable TLS compression to migitate CRIME attack (issue #309)
    OP_NO_COMPRESSION = 0x20000
    ctx.set_options(OP_NO_COMPRESSION)

    # Set list of supported ciphersuites.
    ctx.set_cipher_list(DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST)

    cnx = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
    cnx.set_tlsext_host_name(server_hostname)
    cnx.set_connect_state()
    while True:
        try:
            cnx.do_handshake()
        except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

            READ_ONLY = ( select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI | select.POLLHUP | select.POLLERR)
            poller = select.poll()
            poller.register(sock, READ_ONLY)
            fd_to_socket = {sock.fileno():sock,}
            events = poller.poll(sock.gettimeout())

            rd = []
            for fd, flag in events:
                s = fd_to_socket[fd]
                if flag & (select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI):
                    is s is sock:
                        rd.append(s)

            if not rd:
                raise timeout('poll timed out')

            continue
        except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
            raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
        break

    return WrappedSocket(cnx, sock)
```

Comment: There's no such thing as 'unlimited file descriptors', though sometimes the limit can be very large.  Are you planning to exceed 32k file descriptors?  If so, why?

Comment: Sorry, that should be very large  file descriptors, because the system need many file descriptors.

Comment: Many as in tens, or hundreds, or thousands, or tens of thousands?  Handling even thousands of descriptors is unusual — you need clearly articulated reasons to consider supporting so many descriptors.  That's not to say such systems don't exist, but the people responsible for writing them need to know how to handle them, by starting on systems that use tens or hundreds of descriptors first.

Comment: I don't know how many file descriptors needed, but I need to fix the error like:filedescriptor out of range in select(), it showed the select() is not ok here, so I want to try poll().